# Desire 626 asking for previous gmail account after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, htc-desire, htc, locked-out, google-account

I have bought a secondhand **HTC Desire 626** and when I turned it on it was asking for the previous user's gmail details.

I then loaded up the boot menu/dos menu by holding the **volume -** and **power** for 5 seconds and selected **factory reset**, which ran its process as expected. But the device is still asking for the previous user's gmail info after the reset.

Is there any reason the reset did not clear this link and allow me to start from scratch as I expected?
Or is there a better way of achieving the result I desire (sorry, pun totally intended!)

Comment: I think it has some "lock" security so someone can't easily reuse the device if it has been stolen.

Comment: So unless I can get a response from the seller I am stuck by the sounds of it!

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be it.